# Hashmap doesn't return an int?

Tags: java, hashmap, bukkit

I have two hash map's:

```
private HashMap<UUID, Integer> codeMap = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();
private HashMap<Integer, UUID> uuidMap = new HashMap<Integer, UUID>();
```

I have added the below data to the hashmap:

```
Integer randomcode = new Random().nextInt(800000)+200000;
p.sendMessage("codice:" + randomcode);
codeMap.put(p.getUniqueId(), randomcode);
uuidMap.put(randomcode, p.getUniqueId());
return true;
```

This below code represents the player exit event:
even after the player exits , the code still exists in the hashmap

```
Integer code = this.codeMap.get(e.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
UUID uuid = this.uuidMap.get(code);
this.codeMap.remove(uuid);
this.uuidMap.remove(code);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `p.getUniqueId()` twice, call it once as shown below:

```
Integer randomcode = new Random().nextInt(800000)+200000;

// Store the value returned by p.getUniqueId() to a variable
UUID uuid = p.getUniqueId();

p.sendMessage("codice:" + randomcode);
codeMap.put(uuid, randomcode);
uuidMap.put(randomcode, uuid);
return true;
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Player#getUniqueId()`?

Comment: more than redirecting you to docs I don't know what to do, it is a method created by bukkit to take the uuid of the player, in case you want to have a look at the documents: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/OfflinePlayer.html (
because I don't know how to explain it)